# Initializing a variable and using that in the if clause

Tags: php, if-statement, operators

`if($y=3){echo $y;}` and `if($y=1 and $y>2){echo $y;}` work as expected. However, I wonder why it's not possible to use this `if($x=1 && $x>3){echo $x;}` , which returns `Notice: Undefined variable: x`. (`and` operator has higher precedence than `&&`) If `&&` first evaluates the right operand and after that evaluates the left hand shouldn't it work?

Comment: `if($y=3 and y>2){echo $y;} work as expected` what so you expect using not declared constant `y` ?

Comment: Change it to `if(($x=3)>3)` But still echo won't work since, `$x !> 3`

Comment: @Thamilan  if(false) will would be  easy ^)

Comment: @Thamilan Thanks. but I need to know why that does not works.

Comment: @PHPst Added explanation in answer, check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$y=1 and $y>2` **works as you expected** because:

As per [operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) rule, `=` has higher precedence than `and`. So, it evaluates as:

```
($y = 1) $y>2
```

So, assignment takes place. (Expression inside parentheses evaluates first)

---

2. `$x=1 && $x>3` **doesn't work as you expected** because:

As per [operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) rule, `&&` has higher precendence than `=`. So, it evaluates as:

```
$x=(1 && $x)>3
```

Naturally, `$x` is compared with `1` which is undeclared initially. So the `undefined variable` error pops up. So if you want to change the order, change the expression to:

```
($x=3) && $x>2
```

So your `if` will look like:

```
if(($x=3) && $x>2) {
    echo $x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($y=1 and $y>2){echo $y;}
```

"=" assignment operator has higher precedence than "and".

"=" assignment operator initialize $y and works as expected.

```
if($x=1 && $x>3){echo $x;}
```

"=" assignment operator has lower precedence than "&&".

"&&" operator execute before assignment, hence in this case $x is not defined/initialized and which returns Notice : Undefined variable : x.